# How does HTTP header field "Connection: Keep-Alive" works?

Tags: http, http-headers

When the field `Connection: Keep-Alive` is set inside a HTTP request, the connection is not closed after the response is sent.

How does the client and the server knows that the data is over?

The only way I believe this works is by setting the field `Content-Length` at the HTTP request and the response.

Is there any other way?

Comment: The answer is in the specification: http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/draft-ietf-httpbis-p1-messaging-25.html#message.body.length